# Passing additional data into a hibernate postInsertEvent Listener

Tags: java, hibernate

I was wondering if there is any way to pass an extra data item into a PostInsertEvent / PostUpdateEvent.  Or a reasonable way to cache the data item and match it up in the PostInsertEvent/ PostUpdateEvent.

So for example say

In Table 1 
   record a has an id value which I have in a variable 
   I insert record b which has no data relationship in it with record a (and doesn't have the record a id in it

Then in the PostInsertEvent I want to insert a record into table 2 which is mainly from the contents of record b (so is contained in the PostInsertEvent entity object) but also I would like to include the id variable in my code from record a.

Apologies this is very convoluted but I wondered if there is a realistic way to do it (essentially 'inject' a java app value into the PostxxxEvent method) ?

Comment: Im trying to do something similar. We need the data that is in the event listener to grab what fields have changed in our DB, but we'd like to store some additional info with it. Were you able to achieve this?